# Why window.opener not working in Internet explore 9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a JSP file which contains the following javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    window.opener.myfunction();
    window.close();
</script>
```

This works file on Chrome, Firefox. It also works on my Internet Explorer 8 and 9 which runs in VMWare virtual machine. However, a user reports a bug which turns out to be that the window.opener does not work and myfunction is not called. The user uses IE9 as well but running on a native windows machine.

My question is that why it works on my IE9 but not his? Could any of the IE settings causes this?

Many thanks

Comment: What happens? Is `window.opener` null?

Comment: Check this link.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648231/javascript-issue-in-ie-with-window-opener ][1]

Comment: Sounds like either javascript is not enabled, or the windows are in different security zones. The different security zones would make sense if it's just a deployment issue, i.e. everything running locally versus running on the internet.

Comment: You could assign `window.opener` manually from the opener.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example... http://jsfiddle.net/KjBj3/6/

Obviously your popup page will have the markup in it but you get the drift...

```
var win = window.open("", "win","width=200,height=100");
win.document.write('<a href="#" id="close" onclick="window.close();">This is myWindow!</a>');
win.focus();
win.opener.document.write('<p>This is the source window!</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about `window.opener`, and it's not needed if you can modify the opener code. Consider this code that replicates the functionality:

```
w2 = window.open(...);
w2.opener = window;
```

If the opener is yours, let it assign itself as the opener to any open window. If you are worried about concurrency, you can sleep in the opened window if the opener is not set yet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    (function f(){
      if(window.opener){
        window.opener.myfunction();
        window.close();
      }else{
        setTimeout(f,1); //1ms should be enough. If not, wait again.
      }
    })()
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know about IE, but I know in chrome that child windows run on the same thread as their 'opener' so concurrency isn't an issue there, and may not be here either.