# window.opener.location not working in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to redirect from child page to parent page with this javascript:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Close", "ClosePopUp();", true); 


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ClosePopUp() {
        window.opener.location= 'ParentPage.aspx';
        self.close();
    }

</script>
```

It works with Firefox & Chrome. But not with IE 9. 
The error I'm getting is:

`Unable to get value of the property 'location': object is null or undefined`

`alert(window.opener)` returns `null` in IE 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.opener) is a non-standard property and is not available in all browsers. It will also evaluate to `null` if the window wasn’t opened from another window, so it seems pretty unreliable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what can be done to make it work in IE?

Comment: I don’t think you can. See this thread for a possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648231/javascript-issue-in-ie-with-window-opener

Answer (score 2):

After searching for quite a while I have found the solution for internet explorer.
You need to use

> window.opener.location.href='';

Comment: This one worked for IE 9, IE 10 seemed fine with self.opener.location

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use window.open

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

**Update**

I think I have got it now. Add an eventhandler in your parent window to your child's unload event.

```
var win = window.open("ChildPage.aspx");

function popUpUnLoaded() {
    window.location = "ParentPage.aspx";
}

if (typeof win.attachEvent != "undefined") {
    win.attachEvent("onunload", popUpUnLoaded );
} else if (typeof win.addEventListener != "undefined") {
    win.addEventListener("unload", popUpUnLoaded, false);
}
```

This means that when the function below executes your parent page picks up on it.

```
function ClosePopUp() {
    self.close();
}
```

Comment: That doesn’t solve the issue with accessing the parent window from a popup.

Comment: I tried: window.open('ParentPage.aspx', '_parent', '', ''); It got redirected but in new window. (instead of returning to original parent window)